# Implementing a int datatype in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

this may be a completely pointless act, but I have stumbled across the Uint8Array and ArrayBuffer in javascript while reading about the upcoming worker threads in NodeJS.

On a NodeJS platform would it be possible to implement a "uint8" datatype by using a single element in an ArrayBuffer coupled with a Uint8Array?

Some ideas I had on how to do this in typescript follow.

```
class Int8 {
    intStore: Int8Array;

    constructor(init_value) {
        this.intStore = new Int8Array(new ArrayBuffer(1));
        this.set(init_value);
    }

    get() {
        return this.intStore[0];
    }

    set(value) {
        this.intStore[0] = value;
    }
}
```

So I have some questions for whoever is so kind to read this :)

- Is it possible to do?
- Is it a good idea?
- Would this approach use 1 byte to store the uint8? what kind of overhead would be in this approach?

While this might be a pointless exercise I think it would be cool to see if it's possible even if it does not provide the best performance.

Comment: It would be possible; it would also be pointless. JS is [pretty well optimised](https://jsperf.com/float-vs-int-addition/3) regarding integers already (especially if you perform the casts at appropriate times). The storage would be 1 byte... plus the overhead of the `Int8` object and the `Int8Array` object. It's kind of like renting a second house because it comes with a picture frame of the perfect size for the one canvas you need to put somewhere :)